# Foreign key is zero (instead of null) causing Error 1452 in MySQL for go-gorm

Tags: mysql, go, go-gorm

so I have 2 tables in a zero-to-many relation. (Each `File` can have at most 1 `User`).

```golang
type User struct {
    gorm.Model
}
```

and

```golang
type File struct {
    gorm.Model
    UserID      int    `gorm:"default:null"`
    User        User   `gorm:"constraint:OnUpdate:CASCADE,OnDelete:SET NULL;foreignKey:UserID"`
}
```

Now, in MySQL (this problem doesn't occur with SQLite), I get the following error if there is no user created and I update a file with an empty user:

```
Error 1452: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`DB`.`files`, CONSTRAINT `fk_files_creator` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`) ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE)
UPDATE `files` SET `user_id`=0,`deleted_at`=NULL WHERE `id` = 5
```

This is cause it is trying to add "0" as `user_id` when it should be `NULL`. Like this:

`` UPDATE `files` SET `user_id`=NULL,`deleted_at`=NULL WHERE `id` = 5 ``

I managed to fix that for creating using `default:null`, but any idea how to do it for updating as well? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use pointers (`*`) for Nullable values:

```
type File struct {
    gorm.Model
    UserID      *int    
    User        *User   `gorm:"constraint:OnUpdate:CASCADE,OnDelete:SET NULL;foreignKey:UserID"`
}
```

---

And implementing zero-to-many relations needs something like `list`s. For example:

```
type User struct {
    gorm.Model
    Files []File `json:"partList" gorm:"many2many:files_relation_table;"`
}
```